# Problem with Arduino Pro Mini and RC522

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, rfid

I have a problem with a circuit and I couldn't figure it out why is this happening. This could be a silly mistake by me cause I'm not really an electronic expert. So after spending some days struggling with the circuit I decided to ask for help here.

I am using a **5V Arduino Pro Mini** and a RFID Reader Module, **RC522**. Also, since the RC522 works with 3v3 power source and logic level, I used **TXB0108**, an 8-bit voltage level translator for the SPI communication between Arduino and the RC522. And as it's obvious, I needed a 3v3 to power up the RC522 and as a source for TXB0108. So I used a **LF33CV**.

Here is how I connected the parts:

[image: Connecting the parts / not working]

However, it doesn't work. By working, I mean the entire functionality like setting an Arduino IO Pin to HIGH to light up a LED. But, I checked the voltage of different parts of the circuit using a multi-meter and everything seems to be normal.

The way that it works perfectly and I found it accidentally is to use another (and external) 3v3 source to power up the RC522. I connected a regulated 3.3 volts DC supply to the *3.3v pin* on RC522 (first pin from right / power) and the ground the the circuit's ground.

Any Idea why is this happening? Why haven't it worked by the first circuit I explained?

## Update:

Not working schematic (TOP) and working schematic (BOTTOM):
[image: schematics]

Comment: you might want to redraw that tinkercad schematic into a proper one before your draw the ire of the crowd here-tinkercad is great if you don't know how a breadboard works/want to troubleshoot your connection but it really gives no info as to how things are ACTUALLY connected.

Comment: Fritzing can produce real schematics instead of those wiring diagrams.  Get it to produce one, and post it instead of the wiring diagram.  Half of your problem is that circuits are hard to understand if all you can see are the wires.  A proper schematic diagram helps to understand the function of the circuit.

Comment: Yeah, by "tinkercad/fritzing/etc" I really meant ("schematics" with breadboards in them)

Comment: I updated the question. Is it better now?

Comment: Much better.  Upvoted since you took the time to improve the question.

Comment: Your set up looks fine. If the voltages at all the terminals are fine, check the current requirement of the RFID board. You could start debugging on this front as well.